# How to make c3chart take 100% of the width

Tags: c3.js

I use the library C3.js to build a graph on the page. The graph should occupy the entire width of the screen (because I hidden legend and axis), but chart zone always has an indent about 1% from window's width.

Can I make this?

[Example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OWNvdR)

```
axis: {
y: {
  show: false
},
x: {
  show: false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very Strange, you can put negative padding to get rid of it, I have no idea why its there either. you can add `padding: { left: -20, right: -20 }` to your chart object as quick hack around.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oBxPPL

[c3js Padding Options](http://c3js.org/samples/options_padding.html)

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but I can't use static entity for padding because indent depends on window;s witdth. It's about 1.03%. I use negative margin now, but it's weak solution, I mean